# How to get Debian's volume control working with Pulse

Tags: linux, debian, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I finally configured Pulse to work with every application, however using the volume control on my keyboard still controls the default ALSA selected device. How do I change it so it adjusts the current Pulse selected device?

Comment: See my edit comment, but if you want an answer to your second question you should ask it in a separate question since it's answer would be completely unrelated to the main question above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question is still relevant to you since its so old, but its been upvoted 3 times, so I guess I should point out that the standard gnome applet is for alsa.  You can get a pulse applet here:

http://code.google.com/p/gnome-pulse-applet/

Just install and go, have fun.